# How is AndroidAnnotations' @UiThread implemented?

Tags: java, android, annotations

[AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) provides an annotation that allows running a method on the UI thread, no matter from which thread it is called, e.g.

```
void myMethod() {
    doInUiThread("hello", 42);
}

@UiThread
void doInUiThread(String aParam, long anotherParam) {
    [...]
}
```

from [AndroidAnnotations Wiki @UiThread](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/WorkingWithThreads#uithread).

How is this annotation implemented?

I know that annotation generators can generate additional classes, like e.g. inherit Runable. But how does annotation call it's custom code? Can an annotation modify the method itself or the place where it is called?

Comment: Have you looked at the source code?

Comment: @323go Yes but all I found was too abstract to find the place where the trick is hidden.

Comment: And therein lies the problem with your question: If the source was too abstract, and the readily available documentation on annotations wasn't helpful, there's little chance that what we put in a couple of paragraphs here will serve as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the Android Annotations project, but the normal Android Support annotations do not auto-magically switch to the UI thread to call these methods - they are simply an *indication* to the coder (and any code validators) that the method should only be called from the UI thread.

In other words, this code still throws a `CalledFromWrongThreadException`, even though the `@UiThread` annotation is used:

```
import android.support.annotation.UiThread;
...

public class XYZ extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
         super.onCreate();
         setContentView(R.layout.xyz);

         new Thread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                  XYZ.this.updateUI();
               }
         }).start();
    }

    @UiThread
    void updateUI() {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.texty)).setText("Whoops");
    }
}
```

Paraphrasing from the Support Annotations link you referenced in the question:

> If you attempt to call [a @UiThread method] from a method which overrides
>   doInBackground, or if you call into any View method, the tools will
>   now flag this as an error

The **tools** will flag it as an error, but the App can still be built and run (although it will probably crash as above).

Comment: Oh yeah, your are right. Thanks for pointing that out! This can lead to some really hard to debug bugs because AndroidAnnotation's `@UiThread` works entirely different: *No more AsyncTask<Param, Progress, Result>!!* https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/WorkingWithThreads#uithread

Comment: I always thought that i should follow actual meaning of words in attempt to determine meaning of any program sentence. For example, `annotations` are for people to pay attention and on the other hand `directives` are for compilers to follow, am i right?

Comment: @Valentin meaning of words is typically not enough when no context  is provided and the word is not overly self-explaining. "annotation" is a general term that has a specific meaning in Java. One part of that is the existence of an annotation processor that can generate Java code based on annotations. As far as I know there is no such thing as directives in Java (if you're talking about preprocessor directives)